# Firebase cloud functions: choosing extra file to upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

For my firebase application I need some backend functions that would load i18n files and send them to client. I am able to use webpack to bundle the files for deploying. That works fine. But what I would also like to do is to change the content of the files (because phrases in the app may be added or deleted), which is not possible in this case. Is there a way to upload these files along with the scripts?

There is this section in the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies. However, I wouldn't really like to write `"language_namespace": "file:locales/language/namespace.json"` for each file I have.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any easy workaround and I will probably use some other system for the i18n, because this one is overcomplicated and it will not be easy to work with. Anyway, here is the solution in case someone faces a similar problem:

I used `webpack-cli` instead of `tsc` to bundle my files. Here is what my folder structure looked like:

```
root 
 - functions
   - webpack.config.js
   - lib
   - src
     - index.ts // File with the function
   - ...
 - public
   - locales // Locales folder I needed to be uploaded
     - en
       - ...
     - ru
       - ...
     - ...
   - ...
 - ...
```

It seems like firebase will upload anything that it finds in the `lib` folder, so when bundling the functions, I just used `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy locales there. Here is what my webpack config looked like:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    libraryTarget: 'this',
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?/, loader: 'ts-loader', options: { transpileOnly: true } },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/locales'),
      to: './locales'
    }])
  ]
}
```

Then, to prevent webpack from changing normal `require` to `__webpack_require__whatever`, I had to use the `__non_webpack_require__` function, that would then be transpiled to normal `require` and let me read copied files from `lib/locales`:

```
// In case you are using typescript and want to prevent the compiler 
// from arguing that `__non_webpack_require__` is not defined
declare function __non_webpack_require__(module: string): any

export const getLocale = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const { language, namespace } = req.query

  try {
    const translation = __non_webpack_require__(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
    // do stuff
    res.send(translation)
  } catch(e) {
    if(e.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
      res.status(400).end("Couldn't find translation for ${language}/${namespace}")
    } else { /* ... */ }
  }
})
```

After doing this, both `firebase emulators:start --only functions` and `firebase deploy --only functions:getLocale` worked correctly